# expression for doing something two separate times

Tags: expressions

I was making a bottle of coffee, about the size of two cups of coffee,
and someone told me "that's a lot of coffee to drink"

Yes, if I drink all that in one go,
but I was going to drink half first and save the other half for later

I wanted to say something like "I am going to drink it in two separate times"
but the sentence seems quite unnatural to me;

Is there a better way to phrase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say something like the following:

> I am going to drink it <sup><s>in two seperate times</s></sup> on two separate occasions.

---

Or, as a general expression:

> I am not going to drink it all at once.

The latter is a variation of a very common expression:

> Don't [do something] all at once.

Comment: i thought about saying "on two separate occasions" too, but i felt like that phrase is used more naturally for a beverage like an alcohol. like a bottle of wiskey.so you would open up the bottle for today for celebrating my birthday for example, and save the other half for like other special occasions. but for coffee, you would drink it quite casually, like after every meal.
Am I going too far with my thinking ? or the phrase doesn't imply that at all?

Comment: @briannjs You can use *on two separate occasions* with anything. Watching a movie, writing an essay, doing household chores, eating or drinking something, and so on. It certain is not more common with alcohol than anything else. You may be thinking of the phrase ***special*** *occasion*. However, that's not restricted to a *particular* thing, but an event of significance.

Comment: thanks alot sir ! halped me heaps

Comment: @briannjs It's also true that it would be unusual to drink coffee in order to *celebrate* a special occasion. But I can see how the subtlety could have caused you to hesitate.

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> There are two *servings* in here

[Serving](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/serving):

> The amount of one type of food given to one person:
>   *This recipe makes enough for four servings.*

Comment: Another word that can be used is [**helping**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/helping) although it is more usually for food.

Comment: I purely went for Servings because of [this](https://preview.redd.it/neqgpfeu9rwz.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=715e6b93c9943213fa97af70136252e7294998bd)